# Invalidate NSTimer inside UIView sub class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, nstimer

I'm looking for a solution where I'm using NSTimer inside UIView subclass. If I try to performsegue to another view controller, it keeps running in the background. Can anybody help me with this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSTimer must be declared as a property in your UIView subclass so that it may be accessible in your UIViewController where you are referencing that view.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *myTimer;
```

While performing segue.

```
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
       [self.myCustomView.myTimer invalidate];
}
```

Comment: prepareforsegue is not applicable inside uiview subclass. Please read my question once again. It is about invalidating inside uiview subview

Comment: prepareForSegue will be delcared in your UIViewController and your ViewController will have the reference of your UIView SubClass. It must be IBOutlet in your ViewController.

Comment: Still, 1 minute is there :)

Answer (score 0):

try making timer object nil by assigning

```
  [timerObject invalidate];
  timerObject  = nil;
```